# Why can I hear the music but no sound effects?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I can hear the title screen music and the in-game music but no sound effects like clicking or anything else that differs from music. That's really killing the atmosphere + quality since I can't hear when I'm attacked, for example.

I read a whole bunch of reports and posts, but all are either dead or unfixed. Music volume bars on Windows and the game are all fine, I can't spot the cause of this problem.

I unsubscribed and uninstalled all mods - didn't fix it. I un- and reinstalled the game - didn't fix it. I own all addons for the game.

My PC data are as follows:
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1607
Processor: Intel Core i5-3550 CPU 3.30 GHz
System type: 64-bit, x64-based processor

Comment: Sounds like a bit of an odd problem but there are a couple of things I would check. Are your speakers/headphones set as your default audio device in Windows? Have you got the latest drivers for your audio card/motherboard?

Comment: Yes it sounds like an odd and individual Problem, but if you google it, you'll find a lot more peolpe suffering the same pain. I checked my hardware and the drivers - everything is fine and up to date. thx for your attention anyways, bro

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem. I fixed it by disabling surround sound on my G35 headset. So try disabling any form of surround sound.
Oddly enough, when I enable it again right afterwards the sound effects stay just fine.

Comment: WOW Thanks Buddy!
That worked for me. I switched the WIndows Headphone setting from 5.1 to Stereo and I can now hear all the sounds im supposed to hear :)
I had some more Steam-Games like Far Cry 3 that lacked of all the "spoken" sounds and some more.

But now everything wokrs fine. Have a nice evening bro, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Windows 10 Pro on a Z370 motherboard. The motherboard has 5.1 Ch audio ports on the rear-panel and the front-panel has standard headphone/mic ports.

Interestingly, plugging into the front-panel headphone port allowed me to hear both sound effects and music, but I only heard music through the back panel "front speaker" ("green") port. At the time, I heard nothing from the rear-speaker ("black") or central/bass ("orange") ports.

I later got both music + sound effects out of my rear-panel's front-speaker ("green") port by setting Spacial Sound to "Windows Sonic for Headphones", under the settings for Sound > Device Properties.